# Inserting cursive signature to letter in LaTex

Tags: fonts, letters

I am writing a letter and I want LaTex to put a cursive signature between sincerely and my printed name.  When I do it like this, It puts the cursive under the print.

```
    \signature{Jane Doe\\Job Title\\Company Name\\phone #}
    \begin{letter}
    \opening{Dear ConAgra Food Supplier:}
    \closing{Sincerely yours,}
    \LARGE\calligra Jane Doe
    \end{letter}
```

Comment: Try `\closing{Sincerely yours, \\\LARGE\calligra Jane Doe}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the closing, your cursive name and your signature all within the `\closing` command (as suggested in a comment by @Harish):

```
\closing{Sincerely yours,\\[2ex]%
  {\LARGE\calligra Jane Doe}\\[2ex]%
  Jane Doe\\Job Title\\Company Name\\phone num%
}
```

The `[2ex]` after the newline commands specify how much vertical space to add between the lines. Change at will.

Remove also completely the line `\signature{...}`, you won't need it.

You can inspect the definition of `\closing{..}` if you look at the source code of the `letter.cls` style file. From there I deduce that there isn't really anything much more subtle that you could do: `\closing` creates an indented parbox, and prints in there the closing itself, a vertical spacing, and then either the specified signature (if any) or the specified name. There seems to be no inherent way to fill in that vertical space it inserts.

Comment: You don't need to put the signature text inside `\closing{}`, though. You can leave that in `\signature...`.

Comment: @cfr ... true, but then you will have a (big) space that's provided between the closing text and the said signature, or you would have to compensate for that with for example a `\vspace*{-<some amount>}`.